# How to modify an "add" method of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on this add method code for hours and can't get my head around it... Any hints / help will suffice.

I have a class Bin that makes an ArrayList of BinItems. The BinItem class takes in a String SKU and its int quantity. What the "add" method is supposed to do in the class Bin is see if there's already a BinItem in the Bin that has the same SKU, if it does, then it will add the quantity.

Here is the instructions given to me "a modified version of the add method. We now need this method to operate as follows: When asked to add a bin item b, it first checks to see if the bin already contains a bin item with the same SKU as b. If it does, then the bin item a that is already in the bin is removed and a new bin item is added whose quantity is the sum of the quantities of a and b. If there is no such bin item already in the bin, then bin item b is added in the usual way."

I can't modify the other classes, I can only modify the 3 methods in class Bin: remove, totalQuantity, and add. My main problem is that I'm not sure how to make a new BinItem in the method add that adds up the quantity and removes all similar SKU's.

Here is my Bin Code

```
public class Bin {
    private String myName;
    private ArrayList<BinItem> myContents;

    public Bin ( String name )
    {
        myName = name;
        myContents = new ArrayList <BinItem>();
    }    

    public ArrayList <BinItem> getContents()
    {
        return myContents;
    }    

    public String getName()
    {
        return myName;
    }

    public void remove (int b)
    {
        myContents.remove(b);
    }

    public int totalQuantity()
    {
       int x = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i< myContents.size(); i++)
       {
           x += myContents.get(i).getQuantity();
       }
       return x;
    }

    public void add ( BinItem b)
    {
        BinItem a = b;
        myContents.add(a);
        for (int x = 0; x < myContents.size(); x++)
        {
            if (a.getSKU().equals(b.getSKU()))
                myContents.remove(a);

        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "Bin " + myName + ":\n";
        for ( BinItem b : myContents ) 
        s += b + "\n"; 
        return s;    

    }
}
```

The BinItem code

```
public class BinItem {

    private String mySKU;
    private int myQuantity;

    public BinItem ( String sku, int quantity)
    {
        mySKU = sku;
        myQuantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getSKU()
    {
        return mySKU;
    } 

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return myQuantity;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "SKU " + getSKU() + ": " + getQuantity();
    }
}
```

The main code

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  Bin bin = new Bin( "A" );
  bin.add( new BinItem( "1234-0", 500 ) );
  bin.add( new BinItem( "1234-1", 25 ) );
  bin.add( new BinItem( "1234-0", 243 ) );
  bin.add( new BinItem( "1234-2", 7720 ) );
  bin.add( new BinItem( "1234-0", 871 ) );
  System.out.println( bin );
}
```

and expected result

```
Bin A:
SKU 1234-1: 25
SKU 1234-2: 7720
SKU 1234-0: 1614
[The bin items may be listed in a different order.]
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680834/how-to-modify-add-of-arraylist/27681078#27681078

Comment: Yes it is, I tried deleting that one but couldn't. I had to clarify that I can only modify some stuff like the following methods in the class and not the other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void add ( BinItem b)
{
    boolean added = false;
    for (int x = myContents.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        BinItem temp = myContents.get(x);
        String sku = temp.getSKU();
        if (sku.equals(b.getSKU())){
            myContents.remove(x);
            int quantityToAdd = temp.getQuantity();
            int bQuantity = b.getQuantity();
            BinItem newItem = new BinItem(sku, quantityToAdd + bQuantity);
            myContents.add(0, newItem);
            added = true;
        }
    }
    if (!added){
        myContents.add(b);
    }
}
```

This goes from the end of the list to the start, and performs the requested checks and removes when necessary.  Then it creates the new BinItem with the combined quantity, and adds the new item to the beginning of the list so it will be hit by the search again.

Comment: The code inside the for loop looks very helpful, however, I tried it and it won't add anything to the BinItem

Comment: Edited to add items that are not duplicates, my bad!

Comment: I think the problem is with the myContents.size(). The bin doesn't have anything yet so it makes the size 0. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Both me and holtc added a new condition which adds a new BinItem into the loop (however I don't know why he has an extra parameter).

Comment: This works, the output goes -0, -1, -2 though, not in -1, -2, -0 like the expected output, but the array list contains all of the correct items.  I use the for loop, only because I prefer for loops over iterators.

Comment: It worked!! wow, thank you so much.... This gave me a headache the whole day and was about to haunt me when I'm about to sleep. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not compiled this program myself, but from what I see in your add method, you are doing a few things wrong.

1. You are making a new variable `a`to your list which already equals `b.`If you looped through the list to compare if `a = b,`then the `if-statement` will always return `true`when you get to your `a`element.
2. You are not looping over your `ArrayList`.If you check your if condition, you are checking if the `variables` `a` and `b` are equal, NOT the elements in the `myContents` `ArrayList`itself.

I haven't compiled this code, but based on the specs above, a modified version of `add(BinItem)` could look like:

```
    public void add (BinItem b)
    {   
        boolean changed = false;
        Iterator itr = myContents.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            BinItem bItem = itr.next();
            if (bItem.getSKU() == b.getSKU()) {
                int oldQty = bItem.getQuantity();
                itr.remove();
                myContents.add(new BinItem(b.getSKU(), (b.getQuantity() + oldQty));
                changed = true;
            }  
        }
        if(!changed) {
            myContents.add(b);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Changed code to use iterator, still not tested though**

Comment: This will add b for every item in the list that isn't equal, when we want to add it only once, so the else condition shouldn't be in the while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I haven't learned the "Iterator" method or hasNext() but it gave me a better sense on how to create add an ArrayList in a method.

Comment: No problem, it is best if you select a recommended answer (either one of our answers may do the job that is required).